# Failed to render simple react example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

```
const HiContainer => (props) {
  render{
    return(
       <h1>Hi {this.props.greet}</h1>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HiContainer greet="hi"/>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What's wrong with this code? It's hard to debug I can't see which lines has problem in the console.

Also when do I need to use `constructor`?

Comment: is there an element in your dom with an id of 'root'? Also there should be a comma after '<HiContainer greet="hi"/>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you are using the `arrow` function in a wrong way.

It should be like this `const HiContainer = () => {}`.
Try this it will work:

```
const HiContainer = (props) => {
    return(
       <h1>Welcome {props.greet}</h1>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HiContainer greet="hi"/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

`constructor` is required when you use `stateful components`, and store the information in state variable, since you are using `stateless components`, `constructor` is not required.

Check `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ej2szg3a/

Check this for Stateless Function Components: https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-state/8.4.html

Comment: problem is you are not using `comma` after element try this: `ReactDOM.render(
  <HiContainer greet="hi"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Comment: check this its working: https://jsbin.com/feloxexubu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: constructor's super is for? like `constructor{ super(props)}` why u need that?

Comment: read this why super is required: http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/03/26/683329

Comment: tq I got it now, great article!

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors, should be

```
const HiContainer = (props) => {
  return(
    <h1>Hi {props.greet}</h1>
  )
}
```

and can be simplify to:

```
const HiContainer = props => <h1>Hi {props.greet}</h1>
```

You may need to learn from the basics, this is arrow function: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: still don't work? https://jsbin.com/jehusanoto/1/edit when to use render or return? why u used return above not render and return??

Comment: This syntax you are using is a functional stateless component. The function itself is a render function, so you don't need to write a `render`

Comment: When you're using a normal, stateful component, you need to declare a render function in the component class. `class MyComponent extends React.Component { render() { return <h1>hi</h1>} }`

Comment: You missed a comma in `ReactDOM.render`: `<HiContainer greet="hi"/>,`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using functional component, which handles `render` method automatically.

The code should be:

```
const HiContainer = (props) => (
  <h1>Hi {props.greet}</h1>
)
```

If you want to add lifecycle methods to the component, you need to convert it to class component.

Comment: Because the jsbin uses the code from original question. Try replacing the const with the code above.